# How to run program after completing one process

Tags: bash, ssh, script

So I have backup.php file which create backup of user account. Using top -c | grep username , 
I could see that process is going on ,

top -c | grep newin shows below

```
11334 root      39  19  128m  38m 7036 S 10.3  0.1   0:00.57 pkgacct - newin - av: 4 - write compressed stream
11351 newin     39  19  130m  33m 2792 S  3.7  0.1   0:00.11 pkgacct - newin - av: 4 - create tar stream
11334 root      39  19  128m  38m 7036 S  9.3  0.1   0:00.85 pkgacct - newin - av: 4 - write compressed stream
11351 newin     39  19  130m  34m 2792 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.15 pkgacct - newin - av: 4 - create tar stream
11334 root      39  19  128m  38m 7036 S 10.6  0.1   0:01.17 pkgacct - newin - av: 4 - write compressed stream
11412 newin     39  19 83172  16m 3856 S  1.7  0.1   0:00.05  /usr/local/cpanel/bin/ftpput /bacupdrive
```

I want to execute mail.sh once the backup process is complete

can you please provide some help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: I used backup.php just for example. You can give me working solution for shell script and I will use it in my script . All i want is find process of user is running or not and if there is no process for user , execute mail.sh script 


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
backup.php && mail.sh
```

the `&&` is a boolean AND operator.  Once `backup.php` completes without an error, it will execute `mail.sh`.  If `backup.php` throws an error, `mail.sh` will not be executed.

If you dont care if `backup.php` throws an error, use a `;` (semicolon) instead of `&&`:

```
backup.php; mail.sh
```

In this case `mail.sh` will execute upon any termination of `backup.php`.

Comment: Thank. but this execute mail.sh without checking process of backup.php is is completed or not. I guess I need while and if else loop here.

Comment: @user8863627 Your comment is wrong. Any of the two commands starts *new* `backup.php` and when it exits `mail.sh` is run (or not, in case of `&&` and non-zero exit status). If you want to trigger `mail.sh` when the already started `backup.php` exits (your question is not clear on this), then this answer does not apply, use [AFH's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1274180/432690). Also if `backup.php` forks into background; or spawns children in background, disowns them and exits; or triggers any daemon to do something then exits -- then you may consider it's "not completed" when it formally is.

Answer (score 1):

I've not run a web server on Linux, so I don't know what processes will be launched when a `php` script runs, but a couple of points occur to me.

(1) The easy way to check whether a program is running is to use `pidof`, which will return an error if it is not found, eg to wait until a process completes, use:

```
while pidof ProcessName; do sleep 1; done
mail.sh
```

(2) However, if a script ends and restarts within a second, you could miss the termination, so you need a more elaborate script:

```
if p="$(pidof ProcessName)"
then while [ "$(pidof ProcessName)" == "$p" ]; do sleep 1; done
fi
mail.sh
```

This will make sure that the PID doesn't change, as will happen on a new incarnation of `ProcessName`.

Obviously, the length of the delay will need to be chosen as a balance between the speed with which you want to respond to the termination and the overhead of over-frequent checks.

A better solution all round would be if your web server has an in-built facility to launch a command on completion of a `php` script.